# External monitor blinks when connected to MBP 13'' 2018 through USB-C to DisplayPort cable

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

When I have my Macbook Pro 13'' 2018 connected to the external display LG 27UL550-W monitor.
The monitor often blinks (becomes black) for a second or so randomly.
It happens even when the MacBook is connected to the power cable.

I connect using Inateck Usb-C to Display port cable
https://www.amazon.de/dp/B075Q5T6JT?ref_=pe_3044161_248799201_302_E_DDE_dt_1

The resolution is set to 1920x1080, that is, the screen renders each pixel with 4 pixels (HiDPI mode) with 60 Hz.
I use macOS 10.15.6 Catalina now although it happened even before.

How to resolve this issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Please add how you are connecting to the monitor as this display offers HDMI *AND* DP connectors and all the Mac has is USB-C/Thunderbolt. So what adapters/cables you are using would help as well. Please add that info to your original question and **not** as a comment.

Comment: @SteveChambers I have added the information about the cable to the post. Thanks!